# Setting firebase sender id is no longer available

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was wondering how I could set the sender id now that this has been deprecated.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, fcm)
```

I know that I can do,

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
```

and get a token but what I want to know is how I can set the sender ID (first parameter in the getToken method) when requesting for the token? or is that not how it works anymore?

Comment: You're only reading the token in the first line, not setting it. What do you mean by "how I can set the sender ID"?

Comment: @AlexMamo actually the sender is ID used when you request for the token has to changed to when you set it?

Comment: @AlexMamo seems that it just picks it up from the google play services file. I guess it's not necessary to set the senderId when requesting for a token.